# Single Guy Wearing a Tallis

Tags: halacha, tallit-gadol

Can a single guy who isn't sefardi or yeki (who's minhag is that single men wear talisim) wear a Shuls talis-gadol during davening? And if so, does he have to say a Bracha? How would the process be?

Comment: R' Soloveitchik definitely thinks that a bachur should wear a tallis and apparently the Soloveitchik family does so, even outside of his branch.

Comment: Why would he make a Beracha on the shul’s Tallis? You only make a Beracha on your own Tallis (unless you’ve borrowed it for the past 30 days).